# AWS Elasticsearch with Magento 2 - Catalog Search indexer process unknown error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch, aws

Magento is running on an AWS EC2 instance. AWS Elasticsearch version is 6.0, and Magento is 2.3.4.

Connectivity is successful when I check the connectivity to AWS Elasticsearch via Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog. I am using

- Search Engine: Elasticsearch 6.0+
- Elasticsearch Server Hostname: https://MyAWSElasticsearchServiceEndpoint.com
- Elasticsearch Server Port: 443

When I do `bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext` I get following error

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_1_v2/_mapping/document] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_1_v2/_mapping/document] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]"},"status":400}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this problem because the version of elasticSearch is too low, and it can be solved by upgrading to version 6.8 or higher.

Comment: thank you for your answer! On this forum all communication is in English. I translated your answer, I hope you don't mind posting in English next time?

Comment: @Gyh yes, this is I was about to post that after upgrading to Elastic 6.8 version it started working. Answer Accepted.

Comment: can you please provide the steps to upgrade elastic search.

Answer (score 1):

- I got this error while re-indexing on bitnami server with magento
  version 2.4. I checked and found ES version 6.5.3.
- I got to magento->admin->stores->configuration->catalog->catalog
  search->Search Engine->... and selected "Elasticsearch 6.x (Deprecated)".
- Flushed the cache and re-index again and successful.

Thanks,

Comment: strange one, it worked for me as well even though I am running 7.10.2 of elastic search